# How do I use Font Awesome Icons in Adobe Acrobat for pdf file?

Tags: pdf, adobe, font-awesome, acrobat

I'm trying to edit a pdf file in Adobe Acrobat.
I can't find a working way to insert Font-Awesome Icons in the pdf.

I've tried several ways but I need to get the original icons which I couldn't get yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy.

1. Download and install the Font Awesome fonts to your system.
2. Open the Font Awesome Cheat Sheet (see link).
3. Copy the icon you want from the cheat sheet.
4. In Acrobat, select the Edit PDF toobar and then Edit.
5. Paste the icon where you want it
6. Set the font to FontAwesome using the panel on the right.

http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/